# How do I render animations in a workspace-like manner? (Blender 2.8)

Tags: rendering, performance

I'm starting to learn how to animate, and something that I have noticed in blender is that it is faster to use a screen recorder (such as OBS) and play back the animation in blender (in Eevee Viewport Rendered mode) in full screen than it is to render the animation itself in (specifically in the engine "Eevee", not "Workspace"). The strange thing is that modifying render, encoding, and render output speed and quality options doesn't seem to have any impact on the rendering speed; it only changes the output filesize and quality. This problem occurs no matter how large my workspace is. Are there any rendering options that will speed up the rendering process to be quick like the workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Speeding up the render

By default, the samples are higher for the Render than for the Viewport (so the render is slower). You can set them in Render properties, under Render.

Also, the render is done at full the resolution, but the viewport is rendered, well, at viewport resolution, which is usually lower. The larger the resolution is, the slower the render is.  You can set the Render resolution in Output properties, under Dimensions / Resolution X and Y.

### Rendering the viewport without external tool

Do you know Blender allows you to export the viewport cleanly, without the need of OBS or whatever ?

In the View menu, select 'Viewport Render Animation'. It will render exactly what you see in the Viewport, and export it as a video file. You can set the Path and the File Format in Output properties, under Output.